# Combining a Gui and Processing

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, processing

I was trying to add a Processing Project into a WindowBuilder Gui. After several different tries I looked up and found this:

http://www.sebastianoliva.com/en/en/2010/05/using-a-processing-sketch-as-a-java-component/trackback/index.html

After creating exactly the same Project I had still some Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (PApplet)
The method init() is undefined for the type PApplet

at processJava.DisplayFrame.<init>(DisplayFrame.java:9)
at processJava.Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

How can I fix These two?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

As of Processing 3, `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet`, so it can't be used as a component in another gui.

You can launch a sketch from Java using the `runSketch()` function, but that will be in its own separate window.